# Bash regex for just numbers and dots

Tags: string, bash

There's a folder with two files in it like: `filename-3.0.1-extra.jar` and `filename-3.0.1.jar`. The number and dots in the middle are the version, which can change. I'm trying to copy `filename-3.0.1.jar` to another folder.
Something like:

```
cp folder1/filename-*.jar otherfolder/
```

But the wildcard `*` matches both files. I'm trying to copy just the file without the `-extra` at the end. So I'm trying to match filename on just numbers and dots when I copy, something like this:

`cp folder1/filename-[0-9.].jar otherfolder/`.

But that's not the right syntax for the regex. Would appreciate any help here!

UPDATE:

I got it somewhat working with this:

```
ls | grep -e "filename-[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.jar"
```

But the regex seems a bit rigid. Is there a way to shorten it to something like `"filename-([0-9]+[\.])+jar"`?

So that even cases like `filename-32.430.3.jar` would also get captured?

Comment: Filename wildcard expressions don't use regex syntax, they use "glob" syntax, which is just different enough to be confusing if you don't keep them straight.

Comment: @covfefe: Check my updated answer for suggested `grep` regex.

Answer (score 3):

Using `extglob` you can do this:

```bash
shopt -s extglob
cp folder1/filename-+([0-9.]).jar otherfolder/
```

Here `+([0-9.])` will match 1 or more of any digits or dots.

---

Based on your edited question it appears you're trying to use a `grep` with a regular expression. You can use this `grep` solution:

```bash
printf '%s\n' *.* | grep -E '^filename-([0-9]+\.)+jar$'

filename-3.0.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
 cp "folder1/${##*.}" otherfolder
```

or

```
 cd folder1 && cp -r -v $(echo -e $(ls | grep -e "[0-9]*\.*")) otherfolder/. && cd ..
```

Comment: I got it somewhat working with this:

`ls | grep -e "filename-[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.jar"`

But the regex seems a bit rigid. Is there a way to shorten it to something like `"filename-([0-9]+[\.])+jar"`?

So that even cases like `filename-32.430.3.jar` would also get captured?

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ ls -1 *.jar
filename-3.0.1-extra.jar
filename-3.0.1.jar
```

You can use a loop and filter out those that match `*-extra*`:

```
for fn in *.jar; do   # with this glob, what DO you want
    [[ $fn != @(*-extra*) ]] && echo "$fn"   # and what you DONT want
done
```

Prints:

```
filename-3.0.1.jar
```

So your loop could be:

```
for fn in *.jar; do
    [[ $fn != @(*-extra*) ]] && cp "$fn" otherfolder/
done
```